# How to save data from a DetailView bound to a ViewModel if the repository is a no-go in a viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, save, viewmodel

we mvvm lovers all know Josh Smith mvvm sample and how he has saved the customer in the detail customer view by injecting the repository object into the customerViewModel`s constructor.

But a viewmodel should not know about repositories. Its just a model of a view nothing must being aware of persistence etc...

How can I register my Action delegate SaveDocumentDelegate on the DocumentViewModel if its set in the code-behind? Actually I should subscribe the delegate in my DocumentController but how can I instantiate the DocumentView in my DocumentController and set it as Datacontext not doing that in code-behind. Only thing that came to my mind is using a contentcontrol in the window and bind it to the type of the viewModel and datatemplate it with the Document UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:DocumentViewModel}">
            <View:DocumentDetailView/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyDocumentViewModel}" />
```

But I do not want to use a control to solve my architectural problems...

**xaml**:(view first approach)

```
public partial class DocumentDetailView : UserControl
    {
        public DocumentDetailView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new DocumentViewModel(new Document());
        }
    }
```

**DocumentViewModel:**

```
 public class DocumentViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Document _document;
        private RelayCommand _saveDocumentCommand;
        private Action<Document> SaveDocumentDelegate;

        public DocumentViewModel(Document document)
        {
            _document = document;
        }

        public RelayCommand SaveDocumentCommand
        {
            get { return _saveDocumentCommand ?? (_saveDocumentCommand = new RelayCommand(() => SaveDocument())); }
        }

        private void SaveDocument()
        {
            SaveDocumentDelegate(_document);
        }        

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _document.Id; }
            set
            {
                if (_document.Id == value)
                    return;

                _document.Id = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _document.Name; }
            set
            {
                if (_document.Name == value)
                    return;

                _document.Name = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public string Tags
        {
            get { return _document.Tags; }
            set
            {
                if (_document.Tags == value)
                    return;

                _document.Tags = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Tags");
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**:

```
public class DocumentController
    {
        public DocumentController()
        {    
            var win2 = new Window2();
            var doc =  new DocumentViewModel(new DocumentPage());
            doc.AddDocumentDelegate += new Action<Document>(OnAddDocument);
            win2.DataContext = doc;
            wind2.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void OnAddDocument(Document doc)
        {
            _repository.AddDocument(doc);
        }
    }
```

What do you think about that idea?

Comment: Of course the Window is fetched by a IDialog/WindowService :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But a viewmodel should not know about
>   repositories. Its just a model of a
>   view nothing must being aware of
>   persistence etc...

The viewmodel connects the model and view together; it is exactly what controls persistence, though it does not *handle persistence*.

We decouple this from other concern by using services.

One way to avoid adding persistence concerns to the viewmodel is by abstracting those concerns into repository interfaces, so that we *can* inject it as a dependency. In this way we can delegate persistence work in the viewmodel, usually in response to the user's interaction with the view.

Comment: When I follow your advise I should inject the IRepository into the ViewModels constructor? Thats exactly Josh smith is doing no interface he is just using an object of type Repository not IRepository.

Comment: I updated the init thread with a sample code, please check Jay!

Comment: @Lisa You can use the class (implementation) or a base class/interface (abstraction). Using an abstraction allows you to substitute a different implementation, which might be an alternative, an adapter, or a stub/mock for testing. As for your update, this seems only to apply to top-level windows. In my experience, there are often "sub-controls" with viewmodels of their own, but here perhaps you only have a window that handles documents without the need for any other viewmodels.

Comment: so injecting a IDocumentRepository to the DocumentViewModels constructor is ok for you?

Comment: hm yes I think you could be right probably you are :P its like MVP pattern the presenter gets the IView injected... thanks! ah there is still one question, the most important one... HOW do I inject the IDocumentRepository when I set the DocumentViewModel to the Datacontext of the UserControl in code-behind?